# Omit rows with 0 in many specific columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very wide dataset with multiple psychometric scales and I would like to remove rows if *any* of a handful of columns contains zero (i.e., a missing response).

I know how to do it when the data frame is small, but my method is not scalable. For example,

```
dftry <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 5, 3, 0), y = c(0, 10, 5, 3, 37), z=c(12, 0, 33, 22, 23))
```

```
  x  y  z
1 1  0 12
2 2 10  0
3 5  5 33
4 3  3 22
5 0 37 23
```

```
# Remove row if it has 0 in y or z columns
# is there a difference between & and , ? 
dftry %>% filter(dftry$y > 0 & dftry$z > 0)
```

```
  x  y  z
1 5  5 33
2 3  3 22
3 0 37 23
```

In my actual data, I want to remove rows if there are zeroes in any of these columns:

```
# this is the most succinct way of selecting the columns in question
select(c(1:42, contains("BMIS"), "hamD", "GAD"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` :

```
cols <- c('y', 'z')
dftry[rowSums(dftry[cols] == 0, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]

#  x  y  z
#1 5  5 33
#2 3  3 22
#3 0 37 23
```

We can integrate this into `dplyr` for your real use-case.

```
library(dplyr)

dftry %>%
  filter(rowSums(select(., 
           c(1:42, contains("BMIS"), "hamD", "GAD")) == 0, na.rm = TRUE) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work using dplyr:

```
> library(dplyr)
> dftry
  x  y  z a  b  c BMIS_1 BMIS_3 hamD GAD  m  n
1 1  0 12 1  0 12      1      0   12  12 12 12
2 2 10  0 2 10  0      2     10    0   0  0  0
3 5  5 33 5  5 33      5      5   33  33 33 33
4 3  3 22 3  3 22      3      3   22  22 22 22
5 0 37 23 0 37 23      0     37   23  23 23 23
> dftry %>% select(c(1:3,contains('BMIS'), hamD, GAD)) %>%  filter_all(all_vars(. != 0))
  x y  z BMIS_1 BMIS_3 hamD GAD
1 5 5 33      5      5   33  33
2 3 3 22      3      3   22  22
>
```

Data used:

```
> dftry
  x  y  z a  b  c BMIS_1 BMIS_3 hamD GAD  m  n
1 1  0 12 1  0 12      1      0   12  12 12 12
2 2 10  0 2 10  0      2     10    0   0  0  0
3 5  5 33 5  5 33      5      5   33  33 33 33
4 3  3 22 3  3 22      3      3   22  22 22 22
5 0 37 23 0 37 23      0     37   23  23 23 23

> dput(dftry)
structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 5, 3, 0), y = c(0, 10, 5, 3, 37), 
    z = c(12, 0, 33, 22, 23), a = c(1, 2, 5, 3, 0), b = c(0, 
    10, 5, 3, 37), c = c(12, 0, 33, 22, 23), BMIS_1 = c(1, 2, 
    5, 3, 0), BMIS_3 = c(0, 10, 5, 3, 37), hamD = c(12, 0, 33, 
    22, 23), GAD = c(12, 0, 33, 22, 23), m = c(12, 0, 33, 22, 
    23), n = c(12, 0, 33, 22, 23)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
>
```